# Extract text from HTML <p> with a particular title

Tags: php, html, dom, html-parsing, domdocument

I have a huge file with lots of entries, they have one thing in common, **the first line**. 
I want to extract all of the text from a paragraph where the first line is:

> *Type of document: Contract Notice*

The `HTML` code I am working on is here:

```
<!-- other HTML -->
    <p>
      <b>Type of document:</b>
      " Contract Notice" <br>
      <b>Country</b> <br>
      ... rest of text ...
    </p>
<!-- other HTML -->
```

I have put the `HTML` into a `DOM` like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;    
$dom->loadHTML($content);
```

I need to return all of the text in the paragraph node where the first line is *'Type of document: Contract Notice'* 
I am sure there is a simple way of doing this using `DOM` methods or `XPath`, please advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking of XPath, try the following expression which selects`<p>` elements:

- whose `<b>` child element (first one) has the value `Type of document:`

  - whose next sibling text node (first one) contains the text `Contract Notice`

```
//p[
    b[1][.="Type of document:"]
        /following-sibling::text()[1][contains(., "Contract Notice")]
]
```

Comment: rather than ask another question, is it possible to extend this expression to include a further line saying "**Country:** United Kingdom" with the Country part in bold? Something like this: `//p[b[1][.="Type of document:"]/following-sibling::text()[1][contains(., "Contract Notice")]/following-sibling::text()b[1][contains(., "United Kingdom:")]]`

Comment: `//p[b[1][.="Type of document:"]/following-sibling::text()[1][contains(.,"Contract Notice")]/following-sibling::b[1]/following-sibling::text()[1][contains(.,"United Kingdom")]]`

Answer (score 0):

With this XPath expression, you select the text of all children of the `p` element:

```
//b[text()="Type of document:"]/parent::p/*/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like using `DomDocument` parsing unless I need to heavily parse a document, but if you want to do so then it could be something like:

```
//Using DomDocument
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$matchedDoms = $xpath->query('//b[text()="Type of document:"]/parent::p//text()');
$data = '';

foreach($matchedDoms as $domMatch) {
    $data .= $domMatch->data . ' ';
}

var_dump($data);
```

I would prefer a simple regex line to do it all, after all it's just one piece of the document you are looking for:

```
//Using a Regular Expression
preg_match('/<p>.*<b>Type of document:<\/b>.*Contract Notice(?<data>.*)<\/p>/si', $content, $matches);

var_dump($matches['data']); //If you want everything in there
var_dump(strip_tags($matches['data'])); //If you just want the text
```